# Why are changes to classes ignored after dom changes?

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I have a price grid that uses relative positioning to move a field around, beneath a box with: `overflow: hidden;`. In this is field, there are absolute-positioned boxes containing prices. When this box is hovered, the matching values above and left of the will change color. In order to achieve this, a class is toggled using jQuery. This initially works.

However, after the grid is moved, the class change doesn't affect the block above the grid anymore. In the Chrome console, i can see the class being added, but it's css-styling isn't applied. No other styles for the element have changed.

I am 100% sure there is no other style-rule influencing the element, it just stops responding to the change in class after the DOM has been altered.

Can i 'refresh' the DOM somehow?

**Edit:**

I've tried to get the relevant code only:

Adding the cell in the first place:

```
$("#price_dates_cells").append("<div id='"+weekday[theBeginDate.getDay()]+"-"+theBeginDate.getDate()+"-"+(theBeginDate.getMonth()-1)+"' class='datecell' style='left: "+( Math.floor( difference / ( 3600 * 24 * 1000) ) * ( cellwidth ) )+"px'>"+weekday[theBeginDate.getDay()]+"<br>"+theBeginDate.getDate()+" "+yearmonth[theBeginDate.getMonth()]+"</div>");
```

Toggle the class:

```
var str_element = "#"+weekday[Bdate.getDay()]+"-"+Bdate.getDate()+"-"+(Bdate.getMonth()-1);
$(str_element).toggleClass("red");
```

and the movement that seems to cause the problem:

```
$('#price_grid').animate({"top": (( ( horizontalMovement ) * cellheight)) }, 'fast', 'linear');
```

[Class not Applied http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/6491/classnotapplied.png](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/6491/classnotapplied.png)

Comment: posting a little bit of your code would help a lot or you can create a jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ough, i feel so stupid now. I had changed the id-structure of the appended elements to ensure them being unique, but i forgot to alter the check that had to prevent double addition of the date-cells. The element did receive the class, and applied its styling, but was covered by an identical element, that did not receive the class.

jQuery logically only added the class to the first element with the specified id, and since that was created first, it would be located under the duplicate.

If only i had clipped the screenshot a little different, i'm sure someone would have noticed :D

Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

`CSS` always give `priority` to the `last statement`. So, if you want to override your `.datecell` div `color` then write `red class after` it write like this:

```
.datecell{
  background-color:grey;
}
.red{
 background-color:red
}
```

*That's happen in your case*

**But**

if you not want `red` override `.datecell` then write like this:

```
.red{
     background-color:red
    }
.datecell{
      background-color:grey;
    }
```

Comment: CSS assigns priority based on selector specificity and *then* order.  Meaning, if one selector is more specific than another, then it has priority even if it comes first.

Comment: @AndyE; yes i know if i write .datecell.red or .parent .red is more specify  then .red but when if the elememt is not more specific like above example then it's priority to the last statement.